# RestSharp causes internal server error in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, restsharp

I am using RestSharp for API calling, but when I post data, I get an internal server error. Here is my code. Content is a generic model which I am passing.

```
private async Task<Message<T>> PostAsyncRestSharp<T>(Uri requestUrl, T content)
{
    try
    {
        var client = new RestClient(requestUrl.ToString());
        client.Timeout = -1;

        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddParameter("application/json", content, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

        var resp = response.Content;
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message<T>>(resp);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

It doesn't even hit the catch block.

> GET CALL

Get call is working fine

```
private async Task<T> GetAsyncRestSharp<T>(Uri requestUrl, string urlParams)
        {
            var client = new RestClient($"{requestUrl}?{urlParams}");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddParameter("text/plain", "", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
            var resp = response.Content;
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(resp);
        }
```

Comment: RestSharp isn't giving the error, the server is. Is it your API? Can you debug it?

Comment: But the get call is working good. You can see the updated code I have also added get call.

Comment: The fact that the GET call works has nothing to do with your other one not working. The only thing I can make a guess at is that, according to RestSharp docs, you should be using `AddJsonBody` instead of `AddParameter` if you want the framework to serialize the data for you.

Comment: Thank you so much addJsonbody done the trick. thumbs up

Comment: its working on local both get and post but when published same error

Comment: Make sure you checked in your code and you are publishing the latest version.

Comment: I am pretty sure about latest publish I have removed all existing files and then kept newly added publish files and folders

Answer (score 1):

According to the RestSharp docs you should use .AddJsonBody method

> We recommend using AddJsonBody or AddXmlBody methods instead of AddParameter with type BodyParameter. Those methods will set the proper request type and do the serialization work for you.

> When you call AddJsonBody, it does the following for you:
>
> - Instructs the RestClient to serialize the object parameter as JSON
>   when making a request
> - Sets the content type to application/json
> - Sets the internal data type of the request body to DataType.Json

https://restsharp.dev/usage/parameters.html#request-body

Your code doesn't work because you're sending T object  without serialization.